# Apply jQuery to each section of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a section of html that is similar to:

```
<div class="ms-row">
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
</div>
<div class="ms-row">
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
</div>
<div class="ms-row">
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
    <div class="ms-image"></div>
</div>
```

I have a jQuery script that should affect each each ms-image div in each ms-row div. Currently, it is only being applied to the first ms-row div. If I do something like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() 
    $('.ms-row .ms-image').hide();
    $('.ms-row .ms-image:lt(6)').show();
});
```

All ms-image divs are hidden except for the first six. I need the first six divs in each ms-row to be shown, not the first six in just the first ms-row div.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P456x/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting all ms-image elements that are children of ms-row elements and of that result set showing the first 6.  What you'll want to do is get the first six of each row instead.

```
$( document ).ready(function() 
    $('.ms-row .ms-image').hide();
    $('.ms-row').each(function(){
        $(this).find('.ms-image:lt(6)').show();
    });
});
```

Or as [@Val](https://stackoverflow.com/users/117000/val) pointed out, avoid `.each` by doing

```
$( document ).ready(function() 
    $('.ms-row .ms-image').hide();
    $('.ms-row').find('.ms-image:lt(6)').show();
});
```

Comment: Ahh ok. I had tried .each() before but I wasn't using $(this).find() and that was the problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can make this slightly simpler by avoiding `.each()` : `$('.ms-row').find( '.ms-image:lt(6)').show();`

Answer (score 1):

You can just hide the image children after 6:

```
$('.ms-row').each(function(){
    $(this).children('.ms-image:gt(5)').hide();
});
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9sW53/1/)

or as @Val propose just in one line:

```
$('.ms-row').find('.ms-image:gt(5)').hide();
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9sW53/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each()`

```
$('.ms-image').each(function(){
   $(this).hide();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() 
    $('.ms-row .ms-image').each(function(){
$(this).hide();
}
    $('.ms-row .ms-image:lt(6)').each(function(){
$(this).show();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() 
    $('.ms-row').each(function(){
        $(this).children('.ms-image:gt(5)').hide();
        $(this).children('.ms-image:lt(6)').show()
    });
});
```

You don't need to iterate over each ms-image and hide them. You only need hide .ms-image if there are more the six of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() 
    $('.ms-row .ms-image').hide();
    $('.ms-row').each(function(){
        $(this).find('.ms-image:lt(6)').show();
    });
});
```